# SELECT * FROM `users` returns only first user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  `users`");
$row = $sql->fetch();
foreach($row as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

Database 'users' contains 29 records, but I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: What database adapter you using? PDO / MySQLi?

Comment: I'm using PDO adapter.

Comment: Use fetchAll() instead of fetch().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql `fetch()` function fetches the next row from a result set only 1 row, whereas mysql `fetchAll()` function returns an array containing all of the result set rows.

So use `fetchAll()` to get all the records from resultset, replace this line

```
$row = $sql->fetch();
```

with

```
$row = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you're only fetching one record.

Try your code like this:

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  `users`");
$row = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach($row as $value){
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

this way you'll get an array of results, so you loop over the array instead of over the properties.

Answer (score 1):

[fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns single elements. Instead try with [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$row = $sql->fetchAll();
```

> fetchAll — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

it will return an array hence, remove `echo $value` and use `print_r($value)`

> fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set only 1 row